# Using Range operator to generate text files named with alphabetical order in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I should write a script to sort words in alphabetical order from specific file and put them into 26 text files named A.txt, B.txt, and so on up to Z.txt.

I was able to implement the following code in Powershell, which output text files named with digits:

````
$Content = Get-Content ".\sample.txt"
$Content = ($Content.Split(" .,:;?!/()[]{}-```"")|sort)
$linecount = 0
$filenumber = 0
$destPath = "C:\"
$destFileSize = 26

$Content | % {
    Add-Content $destPath\$filenumber.txt "$_"
    $linecount++
    If ($linecount -eq $destFileSize) {
        $filenumber++         
        $linecount = 0
    }
}
````

How to change the code to display output text files named with alphabetical order

Comment: just FYI ... this will make an array of uppercase letters >>> `[char[]]('A'[0]..'Z'[0])` <<<. plus, ps7 can treat chars as a range, so you can use this >>> `'A'..'Z'` <<<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Group-Object` to group the words based on the first letter:

```
$Content |Group {$_.Substring(0,1).ToUpper()} |ForEach-Object {
  $path = Join-Path $destPath $_.Name
  $_.Group |Set-Content $path
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's right, and I also wanted to add, so that finally the file extension should be *.txt, therefore we need to add the following expression:

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\path_to_folder -Filter *.* | Rename-Item -NewName {[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.Name, ".txt")}


Or do you have a better option for set a file extension?